# Converting tiff to mode 1 bit images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, tiff, gimp

Is it possible to convert a tiff image to mode 1-bit image using command line tools. I saw it can be done with gimp but I need to run a script so I prefer a solution using packages like imagemagick etc

Answer (score 5):

If the image contents is already black and white, and you just need to convert, use:

```
convert input.tif -depth 1 output.tif
```

If you also require to threshold the image, use something like:

```
convert input.tif -separate -black-threshold 128 -depth 1 output.tif
```

Comment: Is it the same as convert  -monochrome input.tif output.tif?

Comment: Note that flags before the input filename apply to the input, and not the output (at least that's what the man-page says).  That said, the result is not identical.  Check both and choose which suits best for you.  The advantage of using threshold, is that you can tweak it.